# Let $G=(\Bbb Z/12\Bbb Z)^\times$ and $S=(\Bbb Z/13\Bbb Z)^\times$. Show that $\alpha$ is a group action of $G$ on $S$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I have the following exercise:

**Let $G=(\Bbb Z/12\Bbb Z)^\times$**

**1. Write down the elements of $G$. Is $G$ cyclic?**

The solution manual says: $G=\{1,5,7,11\}$

My thoughts: I think i get why $5, 7, 11$ are elements. However I'm not sure if $1$ is always an element, or why $1$ is an element.

Furthermore the solution manual says: $G$ is not cyclic since no element has order $4$.

My thoughts: So why are we interested if they have order $4$? Is it because there are $4$ elements?

---

So anyway the next part of the exercise is where I really get into trouble.

Exercise continued:

**Let now $S=(\Bbb Z/13\Bbb Z)^\times$. We define the map 
$\alpha:G\times S\rightarrow S$ by 
$\alpha([a]_{12},[s]_{13})=[a]_{12}\cdot[s]_{13}=[s^a]_{13}$**

**2. Show that alpha is a group action of $G$ on $S.$**

*My thoughts: So I don't understand the text in the exercise, and don't know how to start on question (2). Can anyone help?*

Thank you!

Comment: I find the post completely unreadable

Comment: Yeah I understand, I got really confused writing it too, because I don't understand the exercise, and have not learned how to write math in here yet. I've tried to make some changes to make it more readable.

Comment: I did some editing, go check how I wrote the formulae.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G$ is the multiplicative group of $\Bbb Z/12\Bbb Z$ whose elements are the classes $\bar a$ such that ${\rm gcd}(a,12)=1$. Thus
$$
G=\{\bar1,\bar5,\bar7, \bar{11}\}.
$$
A group is cyclic, by definition, if there's an element $g$ in it whose powers exhaust all the element of the group. For a group with $n$ elements to be cyclic is necessary and sufficient that there exist an element of exact order $n$.

This is not the case for the $G$ in question since
$$
\bar1^2=\bar5^2=\bar7^2=\bar{11}^2=\bar1,
$$
and so there are no elements of order $4$.

An action of a group $G$ on a set $S$ is a function $G\times S\rightarrow S$ satisfying some requirements (which I will **not** recall here). The main point of the exercise under scrutiny is that before checking the action axioms one has to make sure that the map in question is *well defined*. Since the definition
$[a]_{12}\cdot[s]_{13}=[s^a]_{13}$ involves the choice of a representant of the class $[a]_{12}$ this means that the result must be shown independent of this choice, namely one has to show that
$$
\text{if $[a]_{12}=[b]_{12}$ then $[s^a]_{13}=[s^b]_{13}$.}
$$
For, as observed already by S. Dolan in his answer, Fermat's theorem turns out useful.

I leave the details (and the rest of the problem) to you.

Answer (score 2):

**Part 1**

$1$ is an element of $G$ because it is coprime to $12$. Indeed, its inclusion is essential since it is the identity element.

**Part 2**

The group action on $S$ (if I've interpreted your symbols correctly) is that the element $a$ of $G$ maps $s\in S$ to $s^a$.

You should be able to check the conditions that you have been given for  a group action (identity and compatibility) but ask if you get stuck. However, it might be worth knowing that the reason this works is because, by Fermat's little theorem, $s^{12}\equiv 1$ modulo $13$.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! 
I think I godt it, but this group action is definitley not my favorit topic, so I get stuck in the next exercises as well.

(3) Determine the orbit $G⋅[2]_{13}$ of $[2]_{13}$ in $S$

(4) Determine the stabilizer $G_{[3]_{13}}$ of $[3]_{13}$ in $S$

I've read and watched videos about orbit and stabilizer, but can't seem to convert it to this example.